# Android: signed watchface on Android Wear 5.0 not installed

Tags: android, wear-os

i've a signed watchface, it resists in the res/raw folder of the android mobile app but
after installing the app nothing is to see in the Android wear app. The wear app is running in the emulator, but not on the phone device. Permissions are declared in both of the AndroidManifest.xml files, even the installer logs no errors in logcat.

any suggestions or hints what is going wrong here?

Devices i use:
1.) LG G3 running Android 5
2.) Sony Smartwatch 3 running Android Wear 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. I understand you installed the app on your phone?
2. Can you check your app is among the installed apps?
3. adb logcat | grep "Not granting" on both devices brings anything useful?
4. Go to Android Wear -> Gear icon -> Resync apps.

Comment: * 1. and 2. - yepp, app is installed on the phone
* logcat shows WearablePackageManager with no errors
* apps resynched, but nothing to see.

* now used Android Studio, and it works as expected but only if i kill the Android Wear app on the mobile device and restart it. May be it is a bug in the Android wear app when install the signed app via sdcard

Comment: Did you try using Resync apps instead of killing Android Wear?

Comment: yes, tryed it - without luck. Sometimes the watchface appears in Android wear app, sometimes not. if i tap "sync apps", it shows the toast message, but nothing happens. after about 5 minutes, i can see the watchface in both the wear app in the watch itself

Comment: Oh, so this is unfortunately normal. The app needs to be transferred over BT to the wearable device and it takes 5 minutes in your case. If it eventually lands on your wearable device, it works the way it should.

Comment: Thanks, then all is fine :-)